# Error when checking input: expected lstm_29_input to have shape (None, None, 2) but got array with shape (51, 1, 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

My code is as follows:

```
tfidf_matrix=dataset[:0,10]

model = Sequential()

input_shape = tfidf_matrix.shape

model.add(LSTM(32, input_dim=2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim=2, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=20, nb_epoch=11)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=20)
```

a snippet of my dataset is as follows(It is for a binary classification):

```
197.2468966,210.0796552,0.579310345,899.0698276,721.1689655,95.52396817,90.59689707,2.620225801,80.53794681,152.6919308,0

200.7320616,213.6853999,0.653851798,856.1059428,841.3118122,97.48691388,92.08916212,2.753934571,100.4151651,161.5956683,1

225.5475209,250.124516,0.735856126,878.6098414,924.2562758,110.4606583,101.748855,2.885445826,77.50833011,109.0694556,0
```

I'm continuously getting an error somewhat like this: `"Error when checking input: expected lstm_9_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (51, 10)" in model.fit()`
Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should only use the argument `input_shape` in the first layer of the model. The remaining layers will automatically compute their input shape.

Secondly, you should only use one of the arguments `input_dim` and `input_shape` in your first LSTM layer. The argument `input_dim` specifies how many dimensions each timestep of your sequence has, whereas `input_shape` specifies the sequence length and dimensions. You should **not** include the batch size in the input shape. So, if your training data is of shape `(batch_size, seq_length, dim)`, the input shape of your first layer should be `(seq_length, dim)`.

In your case, it looks like your data has 10 timesteps and only 1 dimension (i.e. one number per timestep). So, your training data should have shape `(batch_size, 10, 1)` and your `input_shape` in the first layer should be `(10, 1)`.